# Why don't we have a background color on IE 8 here?

Tags: css

UPDATED to the real case scenario:

If you see the following on IE8 and you notice that the anchor background color has gone.

```
<a class="button-white" href="/contacts/index">Contacte-nos</a>


.button-white {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 7em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #000;
    padding: .4em 1em .4em; /* tamanho */
    border-radius: .5em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #dddddd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#dddddd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%); /* IE10+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;  
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;   
}
```

I can't mark background as important, other wise, good browsers will have a white background instead of the gradient one.

I've tried to change background to "background-color" no effect.

What could it be ?

We have HTC enabled.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us help you.

Comment: @Madara: just out of curiosity, isn't the jsFiddle enough? Or did you maybe overlook that?

Comment: @besluitloos: In the case jsfiddle dies in the future (which isn't as unlikely as you may think), future visitors from Google would find this question worthless, as they'll have no access to the context of the problem. Hence, the question should be autonomous, and answerable without relying on external services.

Comment: Thanks, pure logic but I hadn't thought of it that way.
So we should also provide answers like that, or at least explain the solution. Not something like "solved it: http://jsfiddle...".
The more you know...

Comment: I've posted what I think, is the issued code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you disable `behavior: url(http://yoururl.com/css/PIE.htc)`, then the button is white in IE8 like it should be.

Your CSS is correct, but there is a override with the htc file.

Comment: I've removed the rule. All worked. Thanks a lot for spotting it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a background. you just don't see it because it's white: http://jsfiddle.net/y5YfE/2/

Edit: change

```
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
```

to

```
background: #f90; /* Old browsers */
```

You should get an orange background. tested in IE8 here on win7.

Comment: Sorry then. I've placed the original code, instead of trying to reproduce it. Here, on IE 8, you will see NO background color on IE browser.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? It works perfectly here.
Change background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */ to background: #f90; /* Old browsers */ - here in IE8 the button gets an orange background.

Comment: have you tried changing the color? I don't understand what you are trying to tell me with that last comment.

Comment: on the link provided (it as been updated), the background container element is defined with another color, other then white. So, I can well keep the white and I should perfectly see the white background on IE 8. I'm now checking on another machine, just to make sure, the issue is NOT a virtual box related one. 1 min...

Comment: Same on IE8 real machine. So the issue still remains.